# How to delete a downloaded APK file in the download folder Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-10.0

How to delete file programmatically in android java ?
I have used the app updater package to download my .apk file but the package did not delete the downloaded .apk file after it has installed it.
This is my code for the app updater

```
private class checkForUpdateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

            new AppUpdater(mContext)
                    .setUpdateFrom(UpdateFrom.JSON)
                    .setUpdateJSON("http://172.16.206.19/REST_API/json_format.json")
                    .setDisplay(Display.DIALOG)
                    .setCancelable(false) // Dialog could not be dismissable
                    .showAppUpdated(true)
                    .setButtonDoNotShowAgain(null)
                    .start();


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            deleteDownloadedFiles();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What ive tried so far :

```
File dl_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File[] files = dl_path.listFiles();

    for (File i :files ) {
        Boolean result = i.delete();
        if(result){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, i.getName()+" has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    return;
```

this will return a false result and the file is not deleted.

Comment: Why are you using an asynctask to call the updater?

Comment: Why do you try to delete all files in that folder?

Comment: because when I put in the button method the progress bar wont work. I tried only deleting one still doesn't work to I tried to delete all. In my case it doesn't matter if the folder is empty in fact it's better if the folder remain empty.

Comment: You can delete the file using another way of FileUtils in java from the directory.

Comment: I dont think that users of your app will agree with emptying the Download folder.

Comment: This is warehouse project using android barcode scanner. The user will only use the application that I've develop to do their tasks. Users will not be able to use the android scanner as a mobile phone.  Either way this is not the main problem. The main problem is not even a single file is being deleted.